# How do I find out details of what software a DNS server is using?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-server

I need to get details of the software being used. I have the IP addresses.

Comment: Why? If you have a legitimate reason to know there should be no reason to ask.

Comment: I second this comment: many attack vectors are based on knowing what type and version of software is being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try querying the respective resource records in the CH class, see [Built-in server information zones](http://www.isc.org/files/arm96.html#builtin). This will most likely fail.

Then you could try the things described in [RFC 4892](http://rfc.askapache.com/rfc4892/rfc4892.html). If these fail, too, you could try to identify the name server by analyzing its behavior, e. g. source port distribution when doing a lot of queries.

And last but not least, you could just ask the administrator of the name server which software he's using. Actually this would be the first thing I'd try.

Comment: Most large public DNS servers have this sort of information disabled, NMAP and similar tools may be able to assist, but you're probably out of luck.

Comment: Is there a website that i could use for something like this?

Comment: Running nmap against a DNS server can end you up on their "people I don't like list". Don't nmap systems without permission from the administrators.